# Trigger errors mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I want to make a trigger that prevent inserting overlaping dates. For example:
If I have an offer "Oferta" with the date from 1/3/2016 to  5/3/2016, I can't insert a new offer with the date 2/3/2016 to 4/3/2016 or 4/3/2016 to 7/3/2016

My SELECT checks that condition I believe. What I don't know how to do is to make an error if such happens. I'm new to triggers and Im having syntax errors, I checked triggers syntax but couldnt find the problem...

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tri_check_date_overlap BEFORE INSERT ON Oferta
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    IF EXISTS(
        SELECT * FROM Oferta WHERE 
             (new.morada = morada AND new.codigo = codigo 
                AND ((new.data_inicio BETWEEN data_inicio AND data_fim) 
                OR new.data_fim BETWEEN data_inicio AND data_fim)
             )
             )   

            /*CALL raise_application_error(3001, 'Not odd number!'); */
            DECLARE msg varchar(255); 
            set msg = concat('Error: That right is not allowed!', cast(new.right as char));
            signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = msg;   

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is ok, I think you just missed the 'then' condition after 'if' and 'end if' before the end of the trigger.